# Differences in "git branch" output after removing and adding again remote repository

Tags: git, git-remote

When I clone some project from remote reopsitory, and then make git `branch -a`.

I got:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Then, if I remove remote repository and add it again:

```
$ git remote remove origin
$ git remote add origin username@server:/path/to/repository.git
$ git branch -u origin/master master
```

I expect something similar, but got different output:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Where this difference comes from, and what does it means? And how can I achieve same output after manual remote addition?

I expect then to see some difference in `cat .git/config` but outputs are same in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remotes/origin/HEAD` is pretty much like symbolic link (it literally was a symlink in the past, but they had to change it). When you `git clone` a repository, the branch linked too `HEAD` will be checked out.

Github and other such services usually provide an admin UI for modifying this HEAD link so you can set a branch other than master as the default checkout branch. But you can also do it via command line using this command.

`git remote set-head origin master`

That will restore your `git branch -a` output to how it was when you cloned.

You can also set up other symbolic references such as `foo`

`git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/foo refs/remotes/origin/master`

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/foo -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I've never seen sym-refs in use other than `HEAD`, but i could imagine a good few scenarios where this could be handy (i.e. if you had a build system that auto-deployed to a test lab of devices, having just a ref your dev team moves around would be good)